# vba access: each Ctl in report.controls

Tags: ms-access, vba

i need all the rectangles on my form to be red when the report opens. how do i do this?

here's my code:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    For Each ctl In fill_boxes.Controls
            If ctl.Name = acRectangle Then
                ctl.Name.BackColor = "#ED1C24"
            End If
    Next ctl
End Sub
```

i get an error OBJECT REQUIRED on this line:     For Each ctl In fill_boxes.Controls

fill_boxes is the name of the report

how do i tweak the code to make all rectangles red on report open/?

Comment: Why on earth would you make them red on report open? Why not just design them red? Furthermore, why report open when load was already suggested to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the BackStyle on the rectangle set to Transparent or Normal - Normal is what you want to be if you want to colour the contents of it.

```
ctl.Name.BackStyle = Normal
```